# Do GUIRunOnce and product key in a VM template work in SCVMM? If so, why are my VMs being spun up not activated?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, scvmm, activation

I'm using SCVMM v3.2.8224 to manage dozens of VMs that run Windows Server 2012 R2 (both Standard and Datacenter). In each VM template's OS properties, I've inputted the pertinent product key from [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn303421(v=ws.11).aspx).  However, upon spinning up a VM, the VM shows as not activated.  I assume this is because, as the article above states, I have to run this on the VM:

```
slmgr /ipk <AVMA_key>
```

This does indeed activate the OS, but if this is necessary, then what is the point of inputting the product key in the VM's properties?  I suppose, specifically, I am asking what supplying that information actually *does*.

In any case, I figured I would ignore the seemingly uselessness of specifying the key there and just throw the above command into the GUIRunOnce portion of the VM template's OS properties and that should work.  But it doesn't.  VMs still spin up as not activated.  What am I doing wrong here?  Does GUIRunOnce only work if you specify an action file?